# Parameters inside Laravel localized string

Tags: php, laravel

I'd like have something like this in the `lang/en/mymsgs.php`

```
'string1' => 'Welcome %1, Please meet %2'
```

I would provide the content for %1 and %2 when getting the 'string1' from my code.

I couldn't find a way to do this. Any pointers?

Comment: `:foo` instead of `%1`, and `trans('string1', [ 'foo' => 'bar' ])` perhaps?

Comment: thanks. if you can write an answer with what you just mentioned her I'll credit you for it.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Laravel message localization uses named, not numeric, parameters.

Rewriting your example message:

```
'string1' => 'Welcome :user, Please meet :other',
```

You can now use, for example:

```
trans('string1', [ 'user' => 'Ainsley', 'other' => 'Hayden' ]);
```

Answer (score 24):

If anyone use string translation for Laravel. They can use like this ->

`__('Some translatable string with :attribute',['attribute' => $attribute_var])`

check the documentation for more https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/localization#using-short-keys

Answer (score 0):

using
__('string1', [ 'user' => 'Ainsley', 'other' => 'Hayden' ])